# cmd.exe --> powershell.exe "-File" and "-Command" in the same line

Tags: windows-10, powershell-5.1

test.ps1 contains:

```
echo ok
```

I have a line in the command prompt (cmd.exe) that needs to call powershell.exe passing both the "-File" option and the "-Command" option.
With this wrong syntax:

```
powershell.exe -File "test.ps1" -Command "echo test"
```

"-Command" and "echo test" are passed as arguments to the "test.ps1" script file. In fact the output is:

```
ok
```

I expect as output:

```
ok
test
```

If, on the other hand, I invert the "-Command" and "-File" options:

```
powershell.exe -Command "echo test" -File "test.ps1"
```

"-File" and "test.ps1" are the simple continuation of the argument of the "-Command" option. In fact the output is:

```
test
-File
test.ps1
```

I expect as output:

```
test
ok
```

Help for the "-Command" option:
"If the value of Command is a string, it must be the last parameter in the command, **any characters typed after command are interpreted as the command arguments.**".
This is a substantially false claim, so a bug should be reported to Microsoft.

**Question:**

That said, what is the right way to write the command?

**Answer Requirements:**

As a solution, I want a method that doesn't call the file using the "-Command" option argument; so, even if it works, I don't want something like this:

```
powershell.exe -Command "echo test; & \".\test.ps1\""
```

**This command will ultimately need to be used as a value in a registry key (the classic subkey "Shell\Open\Command").**

For example for directory `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command]`:

This works:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force }; & \"%1\""
```

This not:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force }" -File "%1"
```

because any characters typed after command are interpreted as the command arguments.

Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
Powershell Version: 5.1.19041.1237 (Integrated in Windows 10).

Comment: Can you try with `powershell.exe -File "test.ps1" -Command "& {echo test}"` pls

Comment: Is there a practical need for this?  How about `powershell echo test; .\test.ps1` or vice versa?

Comment: This command will ultimately need to be used as a value in a registry key (the classic subkey "Shell\command").

Comment: @MarioPalumbo Can you make an example of that?

Comment: This works:
`"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force }; & \"%1\""`
This not:
`"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Command "if((Get-ExecutionPolicy ) -ne 'AllSigned') { Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force }" -File "%1"`
because any characters typed after command are interpreted as the command arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what the practical reason for this is.  with -command, there's a lot you can do.  For example if the script takes an argument:

```
# test.ps1
param ($a)
echo ($a)
```

```
powershell .\test.ps1 $(write-host test;echo ok)

test
ok
```

```
# test.ps1
param ($a)
get-itemproperty ($a)
```

```
powershell -file test.ps1 HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command

(default)    : "C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe" "%1"
PSPath       : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open\Command
PSParentPath : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\Microsoft.PowerShellScript.1\Shell\Open
PSChildName  : Command
PSDrive      : HKLM
PSProvider   : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
```

Comment: Sorry for not saying before what use I will have to do with it: `This command will ultimately need to be used as a value in a registry key (the classic subkey "Shell\command").`